# Node.js Post Login Request stuck for Activision site

Tags: node.js, api, post

i want to login to activision site and after i convert a xsrf token via the 'get' request for the login site, when i try to make a 'post' login with my account details & the xsrfToken i'm getting stuck in the air and nothing pop up to my console and its seems like the program stil running...

This may be because they have "I'm not a robot" [recaptcha] authentication?

I took the code from : https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/5519582/SzzgAefq

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'username': 'myUserName',
  'password': 'myPassword',
  'remember_me': 'true',
  '_csrf': 'xsrfToken' 
});
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://s.activision.com/do_login?new_SiteId=activision',
  headers: { 
    'Cookie': "XSRF-TOKEN=xsrfToken"
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after checking the code, the source of the problem was what I suspected and is because of the verification of "I'm not a robot" [recaptcha] authentication!

Whoever else encounters this problem - what you need to do is generate a script that will connect from your PC browser to their site from a user for whom you manually activated the "Remember me", or you have to pay to a third-party library that will pass the verification for you. Then retrieve the session data from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: could you share your final code, @ZzToP? Github link for example would be amazing, as I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @PedroAccorsi Hey mate i found a video which explains how to handle the problem, if after watching the video you do not get along Feel free to send me a message.

The video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zx1ffazngT8&ab_channel=Vioo